# "Warning: react-modal: App element is not defined. Please use `Modal.setAppElement(el)` or set `appElement={el}`"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, react-modal

How do I fix this warning in console of a React app using the react-modal package:

> Warning: react-modal: App element is not defined. Please use `Modal.setAppElement(el)` or set `appElement={el}`

I have not been successful at figuring out what `el` is supposed to be.

Context:
in my App.js root component file:

```
...
import Modal from 'react-modal';
...
class App extends Component {
  ...
  render(){
    ...  
    <Modal
      className="modal"
      overlayClassName="overlay"
      isOpen={foodModalOpen}
      onRequestClose={this.closeFoodModal}
      contentLabel="Modal"
    >
    ...
  }
}
```

Where `...` indicates code not shown.

Everything works fine, but when the Modal is opened, the following Warning appears in my console:

> index.js:2177 Warning: react-modal: App element is not defined. Please use `Modal.setAppElement(el)` or set `appElement={el}`. This is needed so screen readers don't see main content when modal is opened. It is not recommended, but you can opt-out by setting `ariaHideApp={false}`.

In the [react-modal docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal#app-element) all I can find is the following:

> App Element
> The app element allows you to specify the portion of your app that should be hidden (via aria-hidden) to prevent assistive technologies such as screenreaders from reading content outside of the content of your modal.

> If you are doing server-side rendering, you should use this property.

> It can be specified in the following ways:

> DOMElement
> `Modal.setAppElement(appElement);`
> `query selector - uses the first element found if you pass in a class.`
> `Modal.setAppElement('#your-app-element');`

Unfortunately, this has not helped! I cannot figure out what `el` is supposed to represent.

Here are some of the many property variations I have tried adding to my Modal component:

```
`appElement={el}`,  
`appElement="root"` where `root` is the id that my App component is injected into   
`appElement={'root'}`   
`appElement="div"`,   
`appElement={<div>}`,   
`appElement={"div"}`
```

I've also tried calling `Modal.setAppElement('root');` from inside `src/index.js`, where `root` is the root element that my `App` component is injected into, and index.js is where I do that.

Comment: Sheryl's answer is correct - but just so that you know, "el" usually refers to a ref and is short for "element".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Some solutions are given in [react-modal issue #133:](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/133)

[The problem lies here:](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/133#issuecomment-310854620) 
Depending on when it evaluates react-modal@1.6.5:/lib/helpers/ariaAppHider.js#L1:

- document.body does not exist yet and it will resolve to `undefined || null`.
- if `Modal.setAppElement()` is called with `null` or not called at all with the `<script />` placed on `<head />` (same as above).
- Probably it can also happen if called with a `selector` that does not match any results.

#### Solutions:

#### Browser Rendering:

[@yachaka snippet](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/133#issuecomment-194034344) prevents this behavior by defining the element before placing the `<Modal />`:

```
componentWillMount() {
    Modal.setAppElement('body');
}
```

[@ungoldman answer](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/133#issuecomment-207035185), if you don't want to depend on `setAppElement':

> Inject the bundled application JS into `<body>` instead of `<head>`.
>   Though ideally `react-modal` should wait until the DOM is loaded to try attaching to `document.body`.

#### server-side:

> If rendering on server-side, you must provide a `document.body`, before requiring the modal script (perhaps it should be preferable to use `setAppElement()` in this case).

---

**Update**: 
[react docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/tree/master/docs/accessibility) have been updated to include the information above, so they should now be clearer for users running into this issue.
[react-modal issue #567:](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/576) add information (from issue #133 linked above) to the docs.

Comment: if the modal is used within a component only, can it be mounted such that the overlay covers only that component - and not parent / grandparents of that component ? I tried it, it didn't seem to work, it went back to covering the whole screen.

Comment: It would be useful to have a new solution now that componentWillMount() is deprecated. I couldn't find one.

Comment: `useEffect(..., [])` in a functional component does the job.

Answer (score 59):

Add  `ariaHideApp={false}` to `Modal` attributes.

This should work:

```
<Modal isOpen={!!props.selectedOption}
    onRequestClose={props.clearSelectedOption}
    ariaHideApp={false}
    contentLabel="Selected Option"
    >
</Modal>
```

Comment: From the official docs: It is not recommended, but you can opt-out by setting `ariaHideApp={false}`.

Comment: Better would be to do what it says, since that avoids the accessibility problem the warning refers to.

Answer (score 20):

Just include `appElement={document.getElementById('app')}`  inside your modal like this

```
<Modal
className="modal"
appElement={document.getElementById('app')}
>
```

It will work 100% if app is your central in index.html from where react loads.

Comment: You might need a fallback for type safety as `getElementById` is nullable.

Comment: @MoBeigi `appElement={document.getElementById('root') || undefined}` seems to suffice

Answer (score 13):

This is my TypeScript `Modal` component which wraps `react-modal` v3.8.1:

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactModal from 'react-modal'

interface Props {
  isOpen: boolean
  ariaLabel?: string
}

const Modal: React.FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  ariaLabel = 'Alert Modal',
  isOpen,
}) => (
  <ReactModal
    appElement={document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement}
    ariaHideApp={process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test'}
    isOpen={isOpen}
    contentLabel={ariaLabel}
    testId="modal-content"
  >
    {children}
  </ReactModal>
)

export default Modal
```

Usage in component with `state = { isOpen: true }`:

```js
<Modal isOpen={this.state.isOpen}>
  <p>
    Modal Content here…
  </p>
  <button onClick={() => { this.setState({ isOpen: false }) }}>Okay</button>
</Modal>
```

Comment: It works also in react typescript project.So,upvoted.

Comment: For Next.js + Typescript use <Modal ...  appElement={document.getElementById('__next') as HTMLElement}  ... />

Answer (score 8):

If getting the `Warning: react-modal: App element is not defined...` error when running tests (we were running Jest), you can suppress the warnings by adding the following to your test file:

```
import ReactModal from 'react-modal';
ReactModal.setAppElement('*'); // suppresses modal-related test warnings.
```

Comment: It feels dirty, I wish I could figure out the actual selector to pass in there to get it to work.  But for now, this at least suppressed the warning in my tests, so I'm happy!

Comment: Update on my previous comment.  Once I got past that issue and I could see the dom tree printed out, I saw there was a `<body>` tag at the top of the tree.  So I tried throwing that in there instead of the * and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

The shortest solution is to add
`appElement={document.getElementById("hereIsYourRootElementId")}`

It lets react-modal know where is your root element.

Answer (score 4):

Just put this
`Modal.setAppElement('#root')`

This will solve the warning. The root element coming from inside public folder index.html.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, since it was a pain for me, if you are doing SSR, use the following code to prevent errors server-side:

```
if (typeof(window) !== 'undefined') {
    ReactModal.setAppElement('body')
}
```

You could put this in `componentDidMount()` anywhere you use a modal or I put it in a custom modal component so it's nice and DRY.

Comment: `react-modal` has been fixed upstream, so this should not be a problem anymore.

Comment: Its not, I updated the module but still get this warning.

Answer (score 3):

For Nextjs, I think you can solve this by adding the below to outside your modal component, maybe on top, before the component is declared.

```
Modal.setAppElement('#__next')
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add # before your root element id.

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';


Modal.setAppElement('#root');

const OptionModal = (props) => (
  <Modal
    isOpen={!!props.selectedOption}
    contentLabel='this is the selected option'
  >
    <h3>Selected Option</h3>
    {props.selectedOption && <p>{props.selectedOption}</p>}
    <button onClick = {props.handleCloseOptionModal}>Close</button>
  </Modal>
);

export default OptionModal;
```

here is the reference:
http://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/accessibility/

Answer (score 1):

If you get that warning on testing with the "react-testing-library" here is a solution:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal/issues/576#issuecomment-524644035

using the react-testing-library (https://testing-library.com/) I get rid of that warning with:

```
import Modal from "react-modal";

const { container } = render(<MyComponent />);
Modal.setAppElement(container);

....  // to the testing, use Modal
```

or, if you want to test the modal component directly:

```
const { container, rerender } render(<MyModalComponent isOpen={false} />);
Modal.setAppElement(container);
// now the appElement is set we can show the modal component
rerender(<MyModalComponent isOpen={false} />);

....  // to the testing
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED IN NEXTJS:**
This solved it for me, I simply added an id to the root body in the layout, followed by `appElement={document.getElementById("root")}` in the modal.

**layout.js Component**

```
<body suppressHydrationWarning={true} id='root'>
     <div className='main-container col-12 d-flex flex-row h-100 w-100 col-12 justify-content-start align-items-start'>
          <main className='col-10'>{children}</main>
     </div>
</body>
```

**some Component**

```
<Modal
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}
        contentLabel='Book Modal'
        appElement={document.getElementById("root")}
        style={{
          content: {
            width: "850px",
            height: "85vh",
            margin: "auto",
            padding: "0px",
            border: "none",
            overflow: "hidden",
          },
        }}
      >
      <h1>Content Of Modal Goes Here</h1>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

If having this issue with jest, a good solution is to add this to jest.polyfills.js (we have an old frankenstein app).

```
// React Modal Modal Setup
const Modal = require('react-modal')
Modal.setAppElement('body')
```

Answer (score -3):

Delete this attrib
className="modal"
and run again